# How to copy the file in my workspace to a common build server so that other user can pull from there in perforce

Tags: perforce, perforce-client-spec, perforce-integrate, perforce-stream, perforce-branch-spec

I have a file in my workspace named click.py. I want to copy it to the common build server so that other user can pull it from there. And also it would be helpful if you can tell how to pull it also.

In perforce.

I thought of using a4 copy but I don't know exactly how to use it.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `p4 add` command to add files to a Perforce server.

```
p4 add click.py
p4 submit
```

Other users synchronize their workspaces with the latest files in Perforce via the `p4 sync` command:

```
p4 sync
```